# How can I create a subquery and use it in join?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I want to create SQL query as follows:

```
select *
from vwOrderRNI orni
left join vwOrderRN orn on orn.SysId in 
(
    select associatingid 
    from OrderRNAssociation 
    where AssociatedId = orni.SysId 
    and AssociationName = 'ORNItems'
)

left join vwPOrder po on po.SysId in 
(
    select AssociatingId 
    from PurchaseOAssociation 
    where AssociatedId = orn.SysId 
    and AssociationName = 'PO_OrderRequisitionNotes'
)

left join vwPOItem poi on poi.POrder = 
(
    -- above left join  i want to take po.SysId which is filter because of left join
)
```

How can I make 2nd left join in alias table so that I can use that in 3rd left join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your tables to test this against, but I think this is generally what you are looking for (spacing added for clarity):

```
select *
from   vwOrderRNI orni

       left join (
           select AssociatingId, AssociatedId, AssociationName
           from   OrderRNAssociation
       ) as orna on orna.AssociatedId = orni.SysID and orna.AssociationName = 'ORNItems'

       left join vwOrderRN orn on orn.SysId = orna.AssociatingId

       left join (
             select AssociatingId , AssociatedId, AssociationName
             from   PurchaseOAssociation 
       ) as poa on orn.SysId = poa.AssociatedId and poa.AssociationName = 'PO_OrderRequisitionNotes'

       left join vwPOrder po on po.SysId = poa.AssociatingId

       left join vwPOItem poi on poi.POrder = poa.AssociatingId
```

I'm not sure I joined `vwPOItem` correctly because your comment suggests that you join using `po.SysId`, but your question suggests you use `PurchaseOAssociation.AssociatingId`.  Anyway, you can easily change it to what you need now that the inner joined sub-queries are aliased.

Comment: This answers how to alias a sub-query to be able to reference it in multiple joins.  But I have to agree with @RomanPekar that it's likely not necessary to use sub-queries at all.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without knowing your schema, but I think you could simplify your query like this, looks like you don't need this massive number of subqueries at all:

```
select *
from vwOrderRNI as orni
    left outer join OrderRNAssociation as orna on
        orna.AssociatedId = orni.SysId and orna.AssociationName = 'ORNItems'
    left outer join vwOrderRN as orn on orn.SysId = orna.AssociatingId 
    left outer join PurchaseOAssociation as poa on
        poa.AssociatedId = orn.SysId and poa.AssociationName = 'PO_OrderRequisitionNotes'
    left outer join vwPOrder po as on po.SysId = poa.AssociatingId
    left join vwPOItem poi on poi.POrder = po.SysId
```